# How to locate ttyUSB0 in Xubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ubuntu, avrdude

I have a USB to serial adapter that I need to use with my Xubuntu install.  When I plug it in I can use dmesg and lsusb to locate it.  It is clear that the device is attached to ttyUSB0.  I am used to finding that under the /dev folder (i.e. /dev/ttyUSB0) but when I look in that folder it is not present.  In fact, there are no ttyUSB links of any sort.  There are lots of "tty" but no "ttyUSB".  I've tried searching but with no luck.  Where can the "ttyUSB" links be found?

Update:  As requested I am adding the output of dmesg | grep USB0

> `usb 2-7: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0`

Comment: Can you add the output of "dmesg | grep USB0" to your question?

Comment: Very strange... I tried on a different PC which is running the same version of Xubuntu, installed from the same media, and /dev/ttyUSB0 is clearly visible there.  I'll have to retry the first PC tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I returned to the original PC, where the problem was encountered, and tried dmesg on it.  The results were interesting.

```
[587216.474235] usb 7-1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[587221.340323] usb 7-1: usbfs: interface 0 claimed by ftdi_sio while 'brltty' sets config #1
[587221.342999] ftdi_sio ttyUSB0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[587221.343171] ftdi_sio 7-1:1.0: device disconnected
```

This showed that brltty is disconnecting me.  I looked up the output and found some bug reports which address the problem.  The linked report includes the workaround (remove brltty)

[bug report to Debian](https://lists.debian.org/debian-accessibility/2012/04/msg00016.html)